# Static array with inheriting classes in Java

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, static

I have a litte problem with a static, direct filled array of class files, which inheriting from a superclass

```
 public static Class<SuperClass> classes= new Class<SuperClass>[]{
    ChildClass.class
}
```

seems to be impossible. Intellij says, it requires the Superclass.class, instead of ChildClass.class.

Why is this not possible? Thank you

Comment: You are assigning an array to a non-array variable.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and generics don't mix.

Also a type `Xx<Derived>` is not assignable to `Xx<Base>` (see bazillions of questions on this site).

You may want:

```
private static final Class<? extends SuperClass> clazz = ChildClass.class;
```

The other way around:

```
private static final Class<? super ChildClass> clazz = SuperClass.class;
```

Or use an appropriate collection:

```
private static final Set<? extends SuperClass> classes =
    unmodifiableSet(singleton(
        ChildClass.class
    ));
```

Mutable statics, even if not `public`, are a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because we use `=`(equal) to say left and right hand sides are same..
here you are assigning an array to a non-array variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no generic arrays. You cannot create an array of Class
2. Class is not a subclass of Class

Comment: Thank you. The reason why i need this is the following: I have several filters and I need to define, which filter classes my program is allowed to use. maybe I should just put them as objects into an array on startup or something...